# Get URL before loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome extension that could detect if a user types in a non-url into the url bar. I have gone through a couple of tutorials, and tried what felt like countless lines of code trying to get this to work.

The issue I am running into is if a user types in go/here into the browser, it automatically does a google search and returns me the URL that the browser navigated to. What I would like to be able to do is see what the user typed before the load, and then push them to another site.

Does this seem possible?

Here is a snippit of some of the things I tried.

```
// background.js
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
alert(pathname)

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    //var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    //alert(sPageURL);
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
alert(pathname)
    //alert("From background:" + activeTab.sPageURL + " , " + activeTab.url);
    //chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
    //alert(chrome.runtime.url + ' ' + chrome.runtime.user)
  });
});
```

Comment: `location` object is never updated as-you-type so it won't help here. Anyway, this goal can't be achieved in modern Chrome. In the past it allowed interception of the internal query when typing in the address bar.

Comment: That is a bummer. There is an extension out there that appears to do it called golinks, but I am thinking they do something else in the background as well

Comment: Since extensions can't do that directly, the only explanation is that they intercept the final search URL if it contains their unique query "go/" and redirect it to where they want via chrome.webRequest API.

Comment: Oh so that is interesting. If I were to add something along the lines of "go/" or another keyword of choice, then grab what they type after it, and redirect them to another site?

Comment: Yeah, look for examples, [here's](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webrequest) the official ones.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer to this. If you respond with what you said about the omni search I can accept it as the answer

Comment: I think it'd be more useful if you post a fragment from your eventual solution.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. If I can figure this out I will repost here!